# adding a View programmatically

Tags: android

I'm completely stumped on the use of `ViewGroup` and adding views programmatically. I've got an overriden `ViewGroup` class to which I want to add a `View`.  Here is the constructor:

```
public TestView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText("This is a test.");
    textView.setId(1);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    textView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    addView(textView, 
       new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

I can see everything I draw in the `ViewGroup`'s `onDraw()` override, but I never see the textView getting drawn. This should be easy, so what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know `onDraw` is not being called in ViewGroup by default. Call `setWillNotDraw(false);` in your ViewGroups construktor.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a0b71c59fb33b94a?fwc=1

Answer (score 0):

What is the background color of TestView? You're setting the text color of the TextView to black (RGB 0 0 0); if TestView has a black background, you won't see any text.